I encountered an error message stating "Inconsistent row/column dimensions" when using the leastsq command
I'm looking to perform parameter estimation for a system of nonlinear differential equations using the provided data in the ym matrix for y1, y2, and y3. After that, I aim to fit this data with the solution of these differential equations. However, I encountered an error message stating "Inconsistent row/column dimensions" when using the leastsq command. What could be causing this issue?
clear
function [dy1,dy2,dy3]=quad(t1,t2, p)
   dy1  = -p(1)*t1*t2
   dy2=p(1)*t1*t2-p(2)*t2        //p(1)...p(3) are the coefficients.
   dy3=p(2)*t2
endfunction
// we have the m measures (ti, yi):
m = 3;
tm = [1 2 3]';  //time vector
ym = [1 4 9; 1 5 6;2 7 8]';   //given data for y1...y3
// measure weights (here all equal to 1...)
wm = ones(m,3);
// and we want to find the parameters p such that the model fits the given data in the least square sense:
//  minimize  f(x) = sum_i  wm(i)^2 ( quad(tm(i),p) - ym(i) )^2
// initial parameters guess
p0 = [1; 1];
// error function in least squares
function e=errfun(t1,t2, tm, ym, wm)
   e = wm.*( quad(tm, t1,t2) - ym )
endfunction
// now we could call leastsq
[f,par] = leastsq(list(errfun,tm,ym,wm),p0)  //p(1)....p(3)
// define time vector
tt = linspace(0,6,100)';
yy = quad(tt, par);  //quadratic function using the estimated parameters
scf();
plot(tm, ym, "kx")
plot(tt, yy, "b-")
legend(["data", "fitted curve"]);
xtitle("a simple fit with leastsq")
disp(par)
disp(f)




I don't see any resolution of a differential equation in your code. Moreover your errfun() function dos not have the expected prototype. Considering the way you are calling leastsq , it should be e = errfun(p,tm,ym,wm). Within your errfun() you are calling quad() not accordingly with its prototype, likely.
